# App icon not showing on App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect

I added a build of my ReactNative iOS app to App Store Connect and I'm planning to test it via TestFlight.

For some reason my app icon is not showing app on the website, I added all the images needed using app icon generator online. You can even see the App Store icon is showing up on my Xcode.

[image]

So why is it showing up blank (see snapshot below)?

[image]

Also, why do I have an image which says "Unassigned"? How can I fix that (see first image too)?

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you use incorrect icon size.
[image]
This is screenshot from one of my app where you can see that it must be 60pt, not 76pt

Here you can find needed sizes for app icons
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/foundations/app-icons/
It must be 60x60 points or 120x120 pixels for 2x scale and 180x180 pixels for 3x scale. You just need to check that you provide all needed resourses at the project as guidelines says.